# How to have different implementation of a template class function based on the type of a specific member of the parameterized type

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, conditional-statements, member

So Here is the simplified problem, suppose We have two types

```
struct Shape2D
{
    Vec2 Position;
};

struct Shape3D
{
    Vec3 Position;
};
```

I want to create a template class test

```
template<class T>
class Test
{
  public:
       int method1()
       {
          //return 1 if member T::Position is Vec2,
          //return 2 if member T::Position is Vec3
       }
}
```

such that the following code works

```
Test<A> ta;
Test<B> tb; 
assert(ta.method1() == 1);
assert(tb.method1() == 2);
```

The real context of this problem is for an OpenGL Engine. I want to be able to use the same serialization class for 2D and 3D Vertices Data  without having to write a 3D and 2D version.

Comment: The problem related to polymorphism rather than    templates. Wont it be possible for you to derive shape3d and shape2d from shapes ?

Comment: All depends what exactly you wish to achieve here. Do you just want to test whether you have the right class created?

Comment: Huh, nice. I tried so much to make the problem as simple as possible that ended up to be very different from the one I really have. For the problem at hand overload is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to approach this.

The simplest would be to just use normal overload resolution:

```
template<class T>
class Test
{
private:
    T myT;

    int internal(Vec2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int internal(Vec3)
    {
        return 2;
    }
public:
    Test() : myT{} {}

    int method1()
    {
        return internal(myT.Position);
    }
};
```

This requires that you actually have an instance of `T`.  If you don't, then you'll need to use a template based approach.  That's a fairly deep topic, but one approach that does what you want in your example is this:

```
template <typename T>
int internal();

template <>
int internal<Vec2>()
{
    return 1;
}

template <>
int internal<Vec3>()
{
    return 2;
}

template<class T>
class Test
{
public:
    int method1()
    {
        return internal<decltype(T::Position)>();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of function declarations (definitions are not required in this case), `std::declval` and `std::integral_constant` to solve it at compile-time.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

struct Vec2 {};
struct Vec3{};

struct Shape2D { Vec2 Position; };
struct Shape3D { Vec3 Position; };

template<class T>
class Test {
    static constexpr std::integral_constant<int, 1> method1(Vec2);
    static constexpr std::integral_constant<int, 2> method1(Vec3);

public:
    constexpr int method1() {
        return decltype(method1(std::declval<T>().Position))::value;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<Shape2D> ta;
    Test<Shape3D> tb; 
    static_assert(ta.method1() == 1, "!");
    static_assert(tb.method1() == 2, "!");
}
```

The solution above fails to compile if`T` hasn't a data member named `Position` the type of which is either `Vec2` or `Vec3`.

---

Another possible approach that requires a default value instead could be this:

```
constexpr int method1() {
    return
        (std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().Position), Vec2>::value
        ? 1 : (std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().Position), Vec3>::value
        ? 2 : 0));
}
```

That is the ternary operator used in conjunction with `std::is_same`, nothing more.

---

If you can use C++17, you can also base your solution on `if/else constexpr`:

```
constexpr int method1() {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<T>().Position), Vec2>) {
        return 1;
    } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<T>().Position), Vec3>) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have some oveload function to run different code, say you have `int func (shape 2D x)` and `int func (shape3D x)`, so int your `method1` you just call `func (T.position)` and compiler will help you to resolve the call.